# A bookmarklet to disable the tinymce visual editor?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, bookmarklet

I'm looking for a bookmarklet to disable the tinymce visual editor. This is to say, some code that could be pasted into the address bar to disable the editor (and also bookmarked).

Anyone have any ideas?

The page I want to use it on is using an older version of TinyMce, I think the same version that is used on this page: http://www.imathas.com/editordemo/demo.html

Just to reiterate, I want to remove the TinyMce editor and leave the textarea.

If you would like to see the functionality I am talking about, you could also visit this example page: http://www.matracas.org/sentido/tinymce/examples/full.html and click on the enable / disable buttons below the editor.

The problem here is that the syntax relies on knowing what editor id to put into the .get() function.

```
tinyMCE.get('elm1').hide();
tinyMCE.get('elm1').show();
```

The bookmarklet would ideally just use tinMCE's show / hide functionality, but it would work for all editors on a page.

Comment: is there a specific page you're trying to get rid of it on?

Comment: @gGreg Guida - I added a link to the question showing a page that I would like the bookmarklet to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```
javascript:(function(){var arr=Object.keys(tinyMCE.editors);for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){try{tinyMCE.editors[arr[i]].remove();}catch(e){}}})()
```

More visibly pleasing, but same code:

```
javascript:
(function(){
  var arr=Object.keys(tinyMCE.editors);
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    try{
      tinyMCE.editors[arr[i]].remove();
    }
    catch(e){
    }
  }
}
)()
```

Comment: this looks like the awesome code I was hoping for, just getting this error: TypeError: Object.keys is not a function ?

Comment: looks like we have to add in the code from the compatibility section here and then it should work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys - Maybe this is because i am on FF 3.6 still.

Comment: @cwd: I do use Chrome almost exclusively, but I thought that `Object.keys` was non-browser specific...Glad you found a workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

I start all my bookmarklets with jQuery, although this may work better as a greasemonkey script depending on what you're trying to do.

```
javascript:
function loadScript(url, callback){
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = url;

        var done = false;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function()        {
                if( !done && ( !this.readyState 
                                        || this.readyState == "loaded" 
                                        || this.readyState == "complete") )
                {
                        done = true;

                        callback();

                        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        head.removeChild( script );
                }
        };

        head.appendChild(script);
}

loadScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js", function(){
    jQuery('.mceEditor').remove(); }
```

Comment: If you want to do a greasemonkey script in chrome, you'll have to paste the jQuery source directly into your greasemonkey script. You might need to modify this selector if the pages you're disabling tinymce on screw with the control.

Comment: this actually does not seem to work now that I've tested it. it looks like it removes the editor all together, and I just want it to disable the tinymce part and leave the textbox. I've updated the question with a link.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a TinyMCE remover to my bookmarklet collection:
http://richardbronosky.github.com/Perfect-Bookmarklets/tinymce.html

It has one major advantage over the others I have seen. It restores the content of the textarea back to what was in the source. I don't know if others have experienced this, but we have a web admin to our CMS and TinyMCE, when removed leaves the code altered. I have resolved this.

Here is the code:

```
  for(var i=0;i<tinymce.editors.length;i++){
    var tmpId=tinymce.editors[i].id;
    var tmpVal=document.getElementById(tmpId).value;
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl",true,tmpId);
    document.getElementById(tmpId).value=tmpVal
  }
```

Also on github:
https://github.com/RichardBronosky/Perfect-Bookmarklets/blob/master/tinymce.html